# Can't use COPY FROM to load an "E" into a CHAR(1) column in PostgreSQL from a CSV file

Tags: postgresql, csv

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metering.service_point (
service_point_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
service_point_number varchar (20) NULL,
property_id int NULL,
fuel_type char (1) NULL,
ldz_id smallint NULL,
gsp_id smallint NULL,
supply_start_date timestamp NULL,
supply_end_date timestamp NULL);
```

I'm inserting data from a CSV that looks like this:

```
service_point_number, property_id, fuel_type, gsp_id, ldz_id, supply_start_date
'1717209598220',1,'E',8,,'20180428'
```

Using this command:

```
COPY metering.service_point (service_point_number, property_id, fuel_type, gsp_id, ldz_id, supply_start_date)
FROM 'C:\BillingData\service_point.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

This is the fourth table in a batch loading process, and the first three went fine. This one fails with: `value too long for type character(1)`

However, if I copy the contents DIRECTLY from the CSV and paste it into an `INSERT` query, like this:

```
INSERT INTO metering.service_point (service_point_number, property_id, fuel_type, gsp_id, ldz_id, supply_start_date)
SELECT '1717209598220',1,'E',8,NULL,'20180428';
```

Then it works fine.

My assumption is that this must be a bug. I can work around it by setting the value to NULL, and then fixing it up later. I can also workaround the problem by changing the data type for `fuel_type`, but this seems a little sad.

I guess I'm just missing something simple, maybe something unicode related - like the `E` in my CSV actually counts as 2 characters for some strange reason?

Comment: I just reviewed this, and I bet someone's going to pick up on the `,,` as being the problem  - it isn't this, this works as `NULL`, and I tried it with a value in there and it still didn't work

Comment: Why are you using single quotes around the values?  The default is double quotes as documented here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I thought single and double quotes were interchangeable, and indeed they worked fine for my first two files. Now I know better - thanks!

Comment: Also, the only place I can see double quotes mentioned in that documentation is for an empty string value. Feel free to tell me I'm wrong ;)

Comment: [QUOTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) "QUOTE

    Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. The default is double-quote. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using CSV format."

Comment: Aha! The hyphen caught me out, I searched for "double quote" and only caught the comment above this. Yes, I'm wrong, but surprising that single quotes got me as far as they did.